# Undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass driving me insane in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I don't know what is up, but I was experimenting with GSUB then decided I didn't want to use it anymore so changed my link_to arguments back to:

```
<%= link_to root_url(@user.username), @user.username %>
```

Now I keep getting this error: 
undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

and when I remove that whole line from my show file everything is fine.

or if I change it to this:

```
<%= link_to root_url(:user => @user.username), @user.username %>
```

It's like it has been confused some how and thinks I'm still using the gsub method when I'm not. I've tested or url helpers such as login, password_reset etc and they all work fine. It seems to only be doing this with root_url.

I also cloned a repo of my site from yesterday before I got this issue and guess what?
Same error..

I've never been this frustrated with my programming.

Is there something I can clear? I've tried clearing everything inthe tmp folder still no luck.

routes:

```
Mysite::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :passwords


  root :to                   => "users#new"
  match 'success'            => "users#success"
  match 'login'              => "sessions#new"
  match 'logout'             => "sessions#destroy"
  match 'reset_password'     => "passwords#new"
  match 'setup_new_password' => "passwords#edit"
  match ':username'          => "users#show"

end
```

Comment: Seems like there's missing some code, right?

Comment: Code would help. But you get the same error with the code from yesterday? The problem might be in database. Maybe you have there a record with an nil entry?

Comment: Could you show your routes, too? I'm a bit confused about your `root_url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, as root_url (and root_path) do not have parameters:

`<%= link_to @user.username, root_url %>`

Comment: <%= link_to root_url<<@user.username, @user.username %>   seems to do what I want

Comment: root_url and path don't have parameters. That explains it all. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I think you have your arguments for [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) backwards. It should be:

```
link_to(label, url)
```

The `gsub` method can be triggered by something else deeper inside of Rails. When you get an error, usually you get a stack trace that helps to explain the chain of events leading up to the failure.

Comment: Ha, totally missed that one. Good or at least moderate eyes, sir! :)

Comment: I'm trying to display the url of the users profile. I know how the link_to works as it's used through out my site. This was working earlier today with out an issue. I could see the users url on their profile page: http : // loalhost:3000/username